# Greater than or equal to condition for dates

Tags: vba, excel

Why in this greater than or equal to condition not working.

```
Dim start As String
Dim endat As String
start = InputBox("Enter the Starting Date:        Format:  dd-mon-yy")
endat = InputBox("Enter the End Date:        Format:  dd-mon-yy")
Sheets("Data Base").Range("A1:H2000").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=">=" & start, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & endat
```

Comment: The dates in your input box are in string format. They can be compared with dates in your worksheet if those are in string format as well. However, it will be a string comparison where Feb sorts before Jan because F sorts before J. Of course, this applies to both your criteria and neither one of them should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

If the values in Column E in your "Data Base" sheet are formatted as `Date`, then you can force the `InputBox` to allow only date format.

Using the `Application.InputBox`, together with the `FormatDateTime` function, will force the user to input in a date format.

To learn more about `FormatDateTime` [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251489.aspx)

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub BetweenDates()

Dim StartDate   As Date
Dim EndDate     As Date

Do
    StartDate = Application.InputBox("Enter the Starting Date:", "Format: dd-mm-yyyy", FormatDateTime(Date, vbShortDate), Type:=1)
Loop While StartDate = False ' disable the Cancel option

Do
    EndDate = Application.InputBox("Enter the End Date:", "Format: dd-mm-yyyy", FormatDateTime(Date, vbShortDate), Type:=1)
Loop While EndDate = False ' disable the Cancel option

Sheets("Data Base").Range("A1:H2000").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=">=" & StartDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & EndDate

End Sub
```

Comment: @pramodkarna your'e welcome, mark as "ANSWER"  (click on the gray check mark next to my answer)